# Set GRANT_ACCESS back with SetNamedSecurityInfo

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to grant\deny access to a registry key:

First GRANT_ACCESS

```
AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor(wKey, SE_REGISTRY_KEY, UserName, TRUSTEE_IS_NAME, GENERIC_ALL, GRANT_ACCESS, SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT);
```

and then DENY_ACCESS

```
AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor(wKey, SE_REGISTRY_KEY, UserName, TRUSTEE_IS_NAME, GENERIC_ALL, DENY_ACCESS, SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT);
```

They both worked. After this two calls I'm trying to call the first one again to grant access back. But I can't do it. There is no error messages like ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor returns no error code. And my user account is owner of corresponding registry key. Moreover I still can change permissions manually by regedit under the same UserName.
Is there somethind wrong with AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor method?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use DENY_ACCESS to and SET_ACCESS.
Example:

```
AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor(wKey, SE_REGISTRY_KEY, UserName, TRUSTEE_IS_NAME, GENERIC_ALL, SET_ACCESS, SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT);
```

and

```
AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor(wKey, SE_REGISTRY_KEY, UserName, TRUSTEE_IS_NAME, GENERIC_ALL, DENY_ACCESS, SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since your last call was to DENY access on the given object (Registry key), you cannot expect to successfully access the same object you just Denied access to. This is the reason why you get ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. Since you are the owner of the object, you can of course take ownership of the object and reset the security descriptor as you would like it.

Comment: I do not get ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. AddAceToObjectsSecurityDescriptor returns ERROR_SUCCESS. Well, I can only deny GENERIC_READ for example and then there is still no way to grant it back.

Comment: Since you said "After this two calls I'm trying to call the first one again to grant access back. But I can't do it...", I meant, what happens is the expression of the ACCESS being DENIED, since your 2nd call put DENY_ACCESS. What you could try is to invoke your calls and then try to access the registry object using regedit and see what kind of failure you have.

Comment: OK, I've figured out what is the problem.
To set grant access back I need to call the method with the SET_ACCESS parameter and to remove granted access I need to use REVOKE_ACCESS.
Actually all this explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28aclapi/SetEntriesInAcl%29;k%28SetEntriesInAcl%29;k%28DevLang-C%2b%2b%29;k%28TargetOS-Windows%29&rd=true)